# json web service with nested objects

Tags: php, json, web-services

hi im making an application for a doctor and i have two table a patient table and a consultation table related with one to many relationship when i created a web service i created two web services one for the patient and one for the consultation but m having some complication in the ios application 
what i need is to create only one web service with nested object it mean that each patient will have his consultation in an array inside the webb service ==
can anyone help me please

here is the patient web service :

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('settings.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($base);

mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$req = "select * from patient";
$sql=mysql_query($req);
$nn=mysql_num_rows($sql);

$items = array("items" => NULL);

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $items["items"][] = array(
        "id_patient" => $data['id_patient'],
        "nom" => $data['nom'],
        "prenom" => $data['prenom'],
        "Sexe" => $data['Sexe'],
        "date_de_naissance" => $data['date_de_naissance'],
        "lieu_de_naissance" => $data['lieu_de_naissance'],
        "adresse" =>$data['adresse'],
        "latitude" => $data['latitude'],
        "longitude" => $data['longitude'],
        "telephone" => $data['telephone'],
        "email" => $data['email'],
        "situation_familiale" => $data['situation_familiale'],
        "profession" => $data['profession'],
        "numero_securite_sociale" => $data['numero_securite_sociale'],
        "taille" => $data['taille'],
        "poids" => $data['poids'],
        "situation_familiale" => $data['situation_familiale'],
        "groupe_sanguin" => $data['groupe_sanguin'],
        "allergies" =>$data['allergies'],
        "antecedents_chirurgicaux" => $data['antecedents_chirurgicaux'],
        "antecedents_medicaux" => $data['antecedents_medicaux'],
        "antecedents_familiaux" => $data['antecedents_familiaux'],
                );
}   
    echo json_encode($items,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

and here is the consultation web service

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('settings.php');
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($base);
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');



$patient = (int) $_GET['patient'];
//where id_patient= '".$patient."' 
$req = "select * from consultation ";
$sql=mysql_query($req);
$nn=mysql_num_rows($sql);

$items = array("items" => array());

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $item = array(
                  "id_consultation" => $data['id_consultation'],
                  "id_patient" => $data['id_patient'],
                  "date_consultation" => $data['date_consultation'],
                  "motif_consultation" => $data['motif_consultation'],
                  "taille" => $data['taille'],
                  "poids" => $data['poids'],
                  "tension_arterielle" => $data['tension_arterielle'],
                  "pouls" => $data['pouls'],
                  "temperature" => $data['temperature'],
                  "observation" => $data['observation'],
                  "ordonnance" => $data['ordonnance']
                  );

    array_push($items['items'], $item);

        }


    echo json_encode($items,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

 ?>
```